# how pass content in new page when printing page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I [image]

See above my page structure but I when I printed  multiple  student details  it doesnot show on seperate page I tried using

```
 page-break-inside:avoid;page-break-after:auto;
```

but it will not work

Follwing my javascript sample code

```
     table += '<table style="width: 90%"><tr><td style="width: 5%;"><b>SR. NO.</b></td><td style="width: 15%;"><b>COURSE CODE</b></td><td align="center"><b>COURSE NAME</b></td><td style="width: 15%;"><b>GRADE</b></td><td style="width: 15%;"><b>COURSE CREDITS</b></td></tr>';
    table += SubCal + '</table>';
     table += '</td></tr><tr><td style="height: 5%; border: none; font-size: 12px;">';
       table += '<table border="1" style="width: 99.70%"><tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><b>TRIMESTER PERFORMANCE INDEX (TPI)</b></td><td colspan="3" align="center"><b>CUMULATIVE PERFORMANCE INDEX (CPI)</b></td></tr><tr><td align="center" style="width: 16%;">CREDITS</td><td align="center" style="width: 20%;">EARNED GRADE POINTS</td><td align="center" style="width: 16%;">TPI</td><td align="center" style="width: 16%;">EARNED CREDITS</td><td align="center" style="width: 20%;">EARNED GRADE POINTS</td> <td align="center" style="width: 16%;">CPI</td></tr>';
 table += '<tr><td align="center">' + e.d[a].Term_Credits + '</td><td align="center">' + e.d[a].Total_Earned_Credits + '</td> <td align="center">' + e.d[a].Tpi + '</td><td align="center">' + e.d[a].Total_Credits + '</td><td align="center">' + e.d[a].Earned_Grd_Points + '</td><td align="center">' + e.d[a].Cpi + '</td></tr></table>';
 table += '<div style=" page-break-after: always;">';
 document.getElementById("tbl_Master").innerHTML = table;
```

my html part

```
 <div id="tbl_Master"></div>
```

.

```
page-break-after: always;  
it will work for only html but  when I am passing data using javascript dynamically not working for me
```

Comment: you can't use page-break:after on an empty div (see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp). Also you're not closing the <div> that has the page-break style with a </div>. Lastly, have you tried applying the page-break property to "tbl_Master" itself?

Comment: Thanks ADyson  but when I tried to use this  <div style=" page-break-after: always;"></div>  in print preview first page showing empty  then data but again not formated well on seperate page

Comment: how to apply page-break property to "tbl_Master" itself ?  i didn't get Please show mi how to use

Comment: I tried     <div id="tbl_Master" style="page-break-after: always;"></div> this also